# error while loading <root>, Error accessing .ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/jars/spark-core_2.11-1.4.0.jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

While following an example to deploy an application in Spark, I keep getting the error below while "compile" in sbt.

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/sankalp/Desktop/spark/SVMexample/}svmexample...
[info] Resolving com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework#jersey-test-framework-grizzl[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/sankalp/Desktop/spark/SVMexample/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] error while loading <root>, Error accessing /home/sankalp/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/jars/spark-core_2.11-1.4.0.jar
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compileIncremental for the full output.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed Aug 16, 2015 2:36:53 AM
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: No Spark expert, but have you tried to wipe your Ivy2 cache: `rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache` ? (Warning: sbt will have to download a lot of stuff again from the Internet)

Comment: I tried that, still the same error....

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert, but in my case it helped editing:

project/Versions.scala -> val Spark = "1.4.0" -> "1.4.1".

Although it is actually a mystery to me why it did help :).

EDIT:

On the second thought i've noticed by accident, that the file spark-core_2.11-1.4.0.jar was broken (each time it was downloaded by sbt).

It also helped to replacing .jar with valid one from:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/1.4.0

I suppose it is somehow connected with spark-cassandra-connector build system or repo from which file is downloaded.

Maybe we should file an issue.

EDIT2:

i found out, that broken .jar comes from (at least in my case):

https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/1.4.0/spark-core_2.11-1.4.0.jar

you can see its origin in: .ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/ivydata-1.4.0.properties

i did not manage to find out why it comes from jcenter (https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). maybe it is somehow connected with adding bintray repo to my linux mint or new version of sbt or datastax uses bintray. i will probably investigate later.

Answer (score -1):

The previous suggestions seemed very specific to a particular use case. My solution is inefficient, brute force, but was effective:

1. Reinstall IntelliJ completely